# New motherboard anc CPU, all connected but cpu blinks red

Tags: cpu, motherboard

https://youtu.be/dzRoDpldHmQ

Hi, i have a problem and i can't manage what is wrong
Today i replaced old motherboard with new - x470 aorus ultra gaming gigabyte
Also replaced power supply with new one
Also i changed processor to the new one (ryzer)

Now i connected all cables (motherboard, cpu, sata) but cpu led turns on for red for one second, and turns off

What can be a problem here?
I checked if processor have something bad with pins but all are good

Comment: Your link is not accessible. Please also provide a description of what it links to.

Comment: New link https://youtu.be/dzRoDpldHmQ